# In iOS, is it bad to ship to the app store with uncommented NSLogs?

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store, nslog

I like to use these to debug (can you tell I'm a noob?) and have left them in my code as is when deploying to the app store. Are there any negative implications for this you can personally think of?

I have looked at these resources and I am getting the feeling it's not a good idea:

- http://doing-it-wrong.mikeweller.com/2012/07/youre-doing-it-wrong-1-nslogdebug-ios.html
- https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPSystemStartup/Chapters/LoggingErrorsAndWarnings.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000172i-SW8-SW7

This was also a good resource:

- http://www.theonlylars.com/blog/2012/07/03/ditching-nslog-advanced-ios-logging-part-1/

That said, when you ship to the store and DO keep NSLogs in there, what have you logged?

Comment: This may not be a very helpful response or proper, but I do all the time. I would get rid of any logs that run in loops or log often, but the odd thing logged is totally fine.

Comment: It's worth mentioning that you shouldn't be commenting manually to disable logging in release builds. Define a macro conditionally on `NDEBUG` instead.

Comment: I agree completely with the last part of the blog post the OP linked: We should use breakpoints most of the time, and use logs for debugging only when necessary (e.g., output variable values without interrupting program execution in an interactive app)

Comment: For example, imagine you are developing a content creation/graphic editing app where the user can drag a rectangular selection area on top of a canvas of some sort, and you want to check that your hit tests/2D collision detection/picking logic is working; you might need to log the coordinates of the mouse pointer/touch and the rect's size in real time as you drag, without interrupting program execution, to see if the values make sense.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[image]

Create a snippet with the above settings.  Where it says "debug statement", replace that with:

> `<#debug statement#>`

Now, since the completion shortcut is set to "NSLog", every time you start typing `NSLog`, it will autocomplete to this snippet and you will have the "debug statement" part selected and ready to type over.

You'll never have to worry about commenting out your `NSLog` statements again, and you'll never have to forget about using `#if DEBUG` since the completion shortcut is what you would type anyway.

[Apple's Official Documentation for creating a Snippet](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/recipes/xcode_help-source_editor/chapters/CreatingaCustomCodeSnippet.html) (I've included this link because I think it's really kind of sad that this is apparently the only way to do it?)...

And my explanation...

1. Copy and paste the following code into Xcode:

   ```
   #if DEBUG
       NSLog(<#debug statement#>);
   #endif
   ```
2. Select the entire code block you just copy-pasted.  Click, hold, and drag this code block down to the snippets section (usually in the bottom right corner).
3. Select this snippet to get a screen like this:

   [image]
4. Click "Edit" and fill out the details.  Give it a title and description.  Leave platform on "All", and language on "Objective-C".  Set the completion shortcut to "NSLog", and leave the completion scope on "Function or Method" (what this option defauts to may depend on where you pasted the code to originally and where you dragged it from).

---

As Aaron Brager's answer points out, `NSLog` could be a performance concern, particularly in loops (also in places that don't seem very much like loops but actually are, like `cellForRowAtIndexPath`...).

But more importantly, you may be exposing information you don't necessarily want to be made publicly available.

I'm not saying there doesn't exist something that might be useful to include to present to the end user in the log statements, but personally, I've yet to find it.  How many times have *you* ever investigated the output of an app's log statements to diagnose an issue you were having with it?  How many times have you contacted an app developer and they asked you to check these statements to help diagnose a technical issue you were having?

Answer (score 2):

The Mike Weller post you linked makes the right call. NSLog is for user-facing warnings.

There also might be performance issues, especially within loops, since it uses a string formatter.

You can and should use DDLog or other tools to ignore the debug messages when you make your release build.